# What is the difference between some_list=[a,b] and some_list=[a]+b?

Tags: python, django

In django, seems

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/catalog/')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/catalog/')),
    static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
]
```

are different.
However, in my mindset it seems that some_list=[a,b] and some_list=[a]+b should be same object.
Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = [2]
>>> [a, b] # build a list with the elements a and b
[1, [2]]
>>> [a] + b # build a list with the element a, then build a new list with all the elements from [a] and b.
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact "`static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`" will

```
return [
    re_path(
        r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % re.escape(prefix.lstrip('/')), 
        view, 
        kwargs=kwargs
    ),
]
```

which is a list.

So your first code will get a list like:

```
[url_paterns, url_paterns, ...]
```

Your second code will get a list like:

```
[url_paterns, url_paterns, ..., [url_paterns]]
```